# Primefaces geocode getting 0.0, 0.0 gps coordinates from backing bean

Tags: java, spring, google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I want to get latitude and longitude of a point generated by geocode service using primefaces geocode and I'm stuck. However when I'm trying to get these coordinates from backing bean I'm receiving 0.0 values.

How can I get access to them in time where they have proper values (right after logging to console), not zeros?

Please notice that I'am new to Spring and PF.

Here is my primefaces front end where I want to get access to backing bean class proper variables value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function geocode() {
        PF('geoMap').geocode(document.getElementById('address').value);
    }
</script>

<h:form prependId="false">
    <h3 style="margin-top:0">Geocode</h3>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
        <p:outputLabel for="address" value="Address:" />
        <p:inputText id="address" />
        <p:commandButton value="Geocode" icon="ui-icon-search" onclick="geocode()" type="button" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:gmap id="geoGmap" widgetVar="geoMap" center="#{geocodeView.centerGeoMap}" zoom="2" type="ROADMAP" model="#{geocodeView.geoModel}" style="width:100%;height:400px">
        <p:ajax event="geocode" listener="#{geocodeView.onGeocode}" update="@this" />
    </p:gmap>

    <!-- Here for example I want to show this values -->
    <p:commandButton value="Show values" action="" update="display" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" />

    <p:dialog header="Value" modal="true" resizable="false" showEffect="fade" widgetVar="dlg">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="display">
            <h:outputText value="Latitude: #{geocodeView.latitude}" />
            <h:outputText value="Longitude: #{geocodeView.longitude}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

And backing bean class:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import org.primefaces.event.map.GeocodeEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.map.DefaultMapModel;
import org.primefaces.model.map.GeocodeResult;
import org.primefaces.model.map.LatLng;
import org.primefaces.model.map.MapModel;
import org.primefaces.model.map.Marker;

@ManagedBean
public class GeocodeView {

private MapModel geoModel;
private String centerGeoMap = "41.850033, -87.6500523";
private double latitude;
private double longitude;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    geoModel = new DefaultMapModel();
}

public void onGeocode(GeocodeEvent event) {
    List<GeocodeResult> results = event.getResults();

    if (results != null && !results.isEmpty()) {
        LatLng center = results.get(0).getLatLng();
        centerGeoMap = center.getLat() + "," + center.getLng();

        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            GeocodeResult result = results.get(i);
            Marker currentMarker = new Marker(result.getLatLng(), result.getAddress());
            geoModel.addOverlay(currentMarker);

            // Here are problematic values
            latitude = currentMarker.getLatlng().getLat();
            longitude = currentMarker.getLatlng().getLng();

            System.out.println(latitude);
            System.out.println(longitude);
            }
        }
    }

    public MapModel getGeoModel() {
        return geoModel;
    }

    public String getCenterGeoMap() {
        return centerGeoMap;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with @ViewScoped on the bean (the one from the package with "bean" in it)

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much. So it was bean lifecycle...

Comment: Yes - I think the default is RequestScoped, so you will get a new one all the time. Try it - put a System.out in init()

Answer (score 0):

add the setter of geoModel in the backing bean.